# Unknown provider: $provideProvider angularjs jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I am getting this error: "Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $provideProvider <- $provide". I been stuck for hours googling around. I have seen many examples where it is done this way and I am unsure of what to do.

```
"use strict";


describe('Controller: ProfileCtrl', function ($provide) {
    //load the controller's module
    var mockProfileFactory;
    beforeEach(function() {
        module('profileUpdate', function($provide) {
            mockProfileFactory = {
                get: function() {
                    id: 16
                }
            };
            $provide.value('Profile', mockProfileFactory);
        });
        var ProfileCtrl;
        var scope;

    inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, $provide) {

        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        ProfileCtrl = $controller('ProfileCtrl', {
            $scope: scope
        });
    });
});

it('should have 3 items', function() {
    var things = scope.range(1,3,1);
    expect(things).toBe(3);
});
```

});

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You had a few bonus provides. In particular the one in the inject statement. You can't inject provide, it is only available to modules. Try my changes below.

```
"use strict";


// SEE no provide here
describe('Controller: ProfileCtrl', function () {
    //load the controller's module
    var mockProfileFactory;
    beforeEach(function() {
        module('profileUpdate', function($provide) {
            mockProfileFactory = {
                get: function() {
                    id: 16
                }
            };
            $provide.value('Profile', mockProfileFactory);
        });
        var ProfileCtrl;
        var scope;
        // SEE and neither in the inject here
    inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {

        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        ProfileCtrl = $controller('ProfileCtrl', {
            $scope: scope
        });
    });
});

it('should have 3 items', function() {
    var things = scope.range(1,3,1);
    expect(things).toBe(3);
});
```

});

Have a read about the angularjs concept of providers, and also check your code against this guide:

http://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2013/12/13/how-to-unit-test-controllers-in-angularjs-without-setting-your-hair-on-fire/

Comment: I been trying to fix this for so long that I lost my mind and didn't notice the extra $provide from my first attempt. Thank you, after removing that $provide, it runs! and thanks for the link, i'll be sure to check it out :D

Comment: What does `// SEE and neither in the inject here` mean?

Comment: drawing attention to the important changes (that is where I removed $provide)

Answer (score 4):

$provide is a provider, you can only inject $provide in app.config method, not in
    controller method.